# Circle route in Google Maps (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Does anybody know how to draw circle route (path)? I can't find any solution in the documentation of google maps for android. Yes, I know, that I can draw path with polyline but I want to differ CAR and WALK path. You can see, that it is possible in google maps, when you choose WALKING direction.

Does anybody tried to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Instead of drawing polyline just keep on drawing circle at the route's points(lat/lng)!

Comment: do you have all the lat/lng for required path? then AKAIK just put marker on each point. you can create a custom marker.

Comment: why you need circle 
rather draw polylines with different colors

Comment: Yes, I could do that easier way but when customer say, that walking path will be with circle, so then it will be. @GauravPolekar I cant draw markers, because I haven't markers on every place, only on start and end every polyline and of course, it is a lot of calculating and math to correctly displayed circle by interpolation, right distance, radius, zoom etc.

Comment: Did you found any source for this do draw the circular polyline in google map